# Is it possible to call an argument as a function?

Tags: python

```
def decor(func):
 
  def wrap():

    print("============")
    
    func()

    print("============")
  return wrap

def print_text():
  
  print("Hello world!")

decorated = decor(print_text)

decorated()
```

`func` was an argument in line 1 but it has been called as a function. How?

Comment: Arguments are just values. Functions are first-class objects in Python, so if the argument is bound to a function, then yes, you can call it.

Comment: Because it's both? You're using `decor` as a decorator without even the `@` syntactic sugar, so it's clear you're calling it _with a function_

Comment: Why is a "how" necessary? So we can better answer, can you explain why you think this shouldn't just work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any callable object can be called; functions are just one such kind of object.

When you call `decor`, you pass the function `print_text` as the argument. This binds it to the name `func` inside `decor`, so yes, you can call `func` as if it were a function, because it *is* a function.